# Android location updates Google Maps every second

Tags: android

I want to display location updates every second in android. The problem is that with this code on one mobile phone the location is updated every 30-40 seconds and on another one every 5-6 seconds. How can i solve the problem to update every second? What is wrong in my code? I have the following code

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

private void locateCurrentPosition() {


    int status = getActivity().getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            getActivity().getPackageName());

    if (status == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (ApplicationState.choice_gps_loc == 0&&location!=null) {
            ApplicationState.latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            ApplicationState.longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(Double.parseDouble(ApplicationState.latitude)
                    , Double.parseDouble(ApplicationState.longitude), map);
        }
        Log.e("Location", "nuuuu");

        //  mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
        long minTime = 1000;// ms
        float minDist = 1.0f;// meter
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                this);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
}


private boolean isProviderAvailable() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);

    provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (mLocationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        return true;
    }

    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        return true;
    }

    if (provider != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

    if (location != null && provider != null) {
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Log.e("alta", lng + " " + lat);
        if (ApplicationState.choice_gps_loc == 0)
            addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(lat, lng, map);

        // CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        //       .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(10f).build();
        if (ApplicationState.choice_gps_loc == 0) {
            ApplicationState.latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            ApplicationState.longitude = String.valueOf(lng);

        }


        if (myMarker != null) myMarker.remove();

        myMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("My position/my future destination")
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(ApplicationState.latitude),
                        Double.parseDouble(ApplicationState.longitude)))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

        //if (map != null)
        //  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
        //        .newCameraPosition(camPosition));
    } else {
        Log.d("Location error", "Something went wrong");
    }
}


public void addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(double lat, double lang, GoogleMap map1) {
    if (updatecerc == 0) {

        if (mOptions != null) mOptions.visible(false);
        mOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(lat, lang)).radius(Integer.parseInt(ApplicationState.radius) * 1000)
                .strokeColor(0x110000FF).strokeWidth(1).fillColor(0x110000FF);
        map1.addCircle(mOptions);
        updatecerc++;
    }

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    updateWithNewLocation(null);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}




@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [Fused location APi](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) insteadof LocationManager

Comment: Same story. Nothing changed even with fused location API

Comment: Did you try to pass long minTime into requestlocationupdates as time parameter. You have it set to 0 even though im not sure what 0 does haha

Comment: 0 says it will get the updates as fast as possible. And yes... i have tried it with something >0 like 1000(which translates into 1 second). The problem is that it takes 4-6 seconds for a request on one phone and 30-40 on another one.I cannot figure out what i have missed